# Postgres database has no roles

Tags: macos, postgresql

I recently installed postgres version 9.3.5 on osx 10.10 and I am unable to connect to it with `psql`. I started the server as my own user as follows:

```
jestep$ pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
```

With `pg_ctl status` I confirmed the server was running. However I cannot connect to the server regardless of what username I try.

```
jestep$ psql
psql: FATAL:  role "jestep" does not exist
jestep$ psql -U postgres
psql: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist
jestep$ psql -U _postgres
psql: FATAL:  role "_postgres" does not exist
jestep$ psql -U admin
psql: FATAL:  role "admin" does not exist
jestep$ psql -U root
psql: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
```

Here are the contents of my `pg_hba.conf` file:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

I have checked in `/etc/passwd`, and there is no user called `postgres`, though there is `_postgres`.

This happened to me once before on Ubuntu and I actually had to uninstall postgres and all extensions, reinstall them, and initialize a completely new database. Is there any less drastic approach I can take?

Comment: @wildplasser the issue at hand is that I cannot log onto the database--as anybody. Although the database is running, since it (apparently) has no roles at all there is no way to connect to it.

Comment: How did you create the db cluster? Manual `initdb`? If you ran `initdb` yourself then the superuser role will be the same name as the user who ran `initdb`, unless you passed an explicit `-U` parameter to `initdb`. If all else fails you should either (a) delete the datadir and re-initdb, if there's nothing on there you care about, or (b) start PostgreSQL in single-user mode and create a new role.

Comment: @wildplasser: I cannot log in as user 'postgres', it says the role does not exist. I mentioned this in the original post.

@CraigRinger: I just initialized a new db in a new directory: `initdb -D ~/.local/pgsql`. The output told me that the server would be owned by user `jestep`. However I cannot connect to it as `jestep` or as `postgres`, both times it claims the user does not exist.

Comment: Okay, I stand corrected .

Comment: @CraigRinger a fresh initdb did the job. Maybe it took a second for the old process to shut down. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to make really sure that all `postgres` processes have stopped before recreating the datadir, otherwise bad things happen to the datadir.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this on @CraigRinger's advice by running a fresh `initdb` in a new directory.

---

Note: Deleting your data dir and running a new `initdb` will destroy all existing data, so it's not something you should do if there's anything in your PostgreSQL install you care about.